# Apple Contacts- creating a group with only one of the addresses in Contact card

Tags: contacts

I want to create a Christmas card group from my Contacts list. However, I only want to use the home address and NOT the work address or alternate address. Is there any way I can just pick one of the addresses when I add them to the group?

Comment: iOS? OS X? version? Is this a secular or non-secular Christmas card group?

Answer (score 1):

> If members of a group in Contacts have multiple addresses or phone
>   numbers, you can select which address or number to use when sending
>   email to that group or when printing contact information.

- Choose Edit > Edit Distribution List.
- Select the group.
  You can’t select Smart Groups.
- Click the rightmost column header to choose the information to manage: email (address), phone (number), or (street) address.
- Select an address or number for each member.

Source: From the Help menu in Contacts on Mavericks.